# UWP 'Style' properties not found by Visual Studio 'Edit Additional Templates'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, design-time

Using the **Document Outline** pane in Visual Studio you can right-click a **ListBox** instance and the presented menu has an option that can be used to generate styles for the exposed style properties of the **ListBox**. You can see this below inside the red rectangle: -

[image]

I have created my own control and exposed a **Style** typed property. I want Visual Studio to discover my property and provide the same functionality. But it does not work even when I mark the class with the **StyleTypedProperty** attribute.

Here is a minimal example of the code for a class: -

```
[StyleTypedPropertyAttribute(Property = "Example", StyleTargetType = typeof(Button))]
public sealed class ExampleControl : Control
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ExampleStyleProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "ExampleStyle", 
            typeof(Style), 
            typeof(ExampleControl), 
            new PropertyMetadata(null, OnExampleStyleChanged));

    public ExampleControl()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(ExampleControl);
    }

    public Style ExampleStyle
    {
        get { return GetValue(ExampleStyleProperty) as Style; }
        set { SetValue(ExampleStyleProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void OnExampleStyleChanged(DependencyObject sender, 
                                              DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that attribute is just a definition representing that style property is target to such a control type, it cannot be recognized by Visual Studio or Blend, but would be meaningful for someone who use your control.

Comment: @WPInfo No, it's supposed to work. It was working in VS2015 but is currently broken in VS2017. BTW, `Property = "Example"` is wrong, it should be `Property = "ExampleStyle"`, or `Property = nameof(ExampleStyle)`. But it still won't work though.

Comment: You'd better report this issue on [Visual Studio Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html)

Comment: Yep, just reported it via Visual Studio.